# How do we take command line arguments using arg[] from intellij/eclipse

Tags: java

I was asked to run a program using command line arguments. The command line argument could either be a file or stdin. 
eg:

Your program must accept input from two sources: a filename passed in
command line arguments and STDIN. For example './program input.txt' and './program < input.txt' should work.

Let me be frank, I am not sure whether I am being asked to pass the location of the file or feed the input to the program using STDIN. I am assuming, for now, it's asking me to input the location of the file. How can I do it using arg[0]? Can I use System.in, will that violate the requirement that is being asked from me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure whether I am being asked to pass the location of the file or feed the input to the program using STDIN

Both. As stated, "your program must accept input from *two* sources". So, your program must support both, either taking a file argument or reading from standard in.

For the first variant, the file argument, the file's name will be available in `arg[0]`.

So, if the arg-array contains at least one entry, go with the file argument.
If there is no file argument (`arg.length == 0`), then read from STDIN.

In code, it could look a bit like this:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
  if (arg.length == 0) {
    // work with System.in
  } else {
    File file = new File(arg[0]);
    // work with file
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running the application directly you can pass the arguments from run configuration. For example, in eclipse you can do the following:

1. right click on the project > run as > run configuration
2. In the new windows: java application > "your app"
3. you can find a tab "arguments"

here you can set the arguments for the app in the "program arguments".

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try.